# Magento Configurable Product Option Image

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I have color and size attribute in my product.

Size : 36-38-40-42-44-46-48-50-52-54

Colors: White-Black-Red

After creating a product with this attributes, magento created 30 simple products under configurable product.

At this point i have a problem.

Changing 30 products images one by one is too hard.

So i created a script which is creating a csv for use with dataflow. This method is making this easier but it's not looking like best practice. Also it's creating duplicate image for each simple product. I need to prevent this.

So i am open for advices to solve this issues.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a dataflow import:

- Go to System > Import / Export > Dataflow Profiles
- Add New Profile
- Assign a Name and change Data Format Type to CSV
- Add Field Mappings for **sku** (the unique identifier we'll use), and the **image**, **thumbail**, etc.
- Save.
- Gather all the images you want to assign to the simple products and upload them to your **media/import/** folder on your server (if the import folder doesn't exist, create it).
- Create a spreadsheet with the column headings that map the field mappings you entered above.
- Enter the simple product SKU codes in the **sku** column.
- In the image columns, enter the filenames of the images (`/prod18-black-small.jpg`, `/prod18-orange-medium.jpg` etc) for each SKU code. This is relative to the **media/import** folder, which the dataflow import will look into.
- Once your spreadsheet is done, go back to System > Import / Export > Dataflow Profiles and go to Upload File.
- Refresh the page and then go to Run Profile and select the file from the dropdown.
- Click Run Profile, and it should import the images for every SKU code you entered in the spreadsheet.

I use the above all the time, I found the following link years ago when using Magento 1.7 and its been safely bookmarked ever since!: https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/05/importing-product-images-via-csv-in-magento-1-7-0-0/